# My report works properly in Eclipse but throws "No query executer factory registered for the 'MongoDbQuery'" with jar file

Tags: java, mongodb, jasper-reports

I want to open a report file with extension `.jrxml` the file work fine with code compilation in Eclipse IDE. When I generate a jar file it throws an exception. I can't find out what should I do to fix this.

I tried to ensure that my maven dependencies are extracted in jar file and it does, then I google it in google but cant figure out the solutions as it is not straight froward.

**My function to open report**

```
InitializationService initializationService = ServiceUtil.getApplicationService()
                                              .getInitializationService();

    String host =initializationService.getHost();
    String port =""+initializationService.getPort();

    ProjectService entityService = ServiceUtil.getApplicationService().getProjectService();
    List<Project> projects= entityService.getAll();
    String run_Project_name = projects.get(0).getRuntimeProject();

    System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
    String mongoURI = "mongodb://"+host+":"+port+"/"+run_Project_name;
    String report = reportDisplayDto.getReportPath();
    MongoDbConnection mongConnection = null;
    try {
        mongConnection = new MongoDbConnection(mongoURI, null, null);
        JasperReport jasperReport  =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
        JasperPrint jp= JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,mongConnection);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 16; Error
>   at line 35 char 16: No query executer factory registered for the
>   'MongoDbQuery' language.
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:301)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:284)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:273)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:218)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:193)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:184)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:285)
>
> ....
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:297)
>           ... 47 more Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer
>   factory registered for the 'MongoDbQuery' language.
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRQueryExecuterUtils.getExecuterFactory(JRQueryExecuterUtils.java:114)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.queryLanguageChanged(JRDesignDataset.java:1181)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.setQuery(JRDesignDataset.java:648)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setQuery(JasperDesign.java:832)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
JRProperties.setProperty ("net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.MongoDbQuery", "com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryExecuterFactory");
mongConnection = new MongoDbConnection(mongoURI, null, null);
JasperReport jasperReport  =JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
JasperPrint jp= JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,mongConnection);
// JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
 JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
} catch (JRException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        `enter code here`}
```