# No query executer factory registered for the "MongoDbQuery" language in Jasper

Tags: java, mongodb, jasper-reports

I want to report the difference between endDate and startDate in assignment collection. I created a template in Jasper Studio.

```
@Document(collection = "assignment")
public class Assignment {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String bookId;

    private String memberId;

    private LocalDate startDate;

    private LocalDate endDate;

    private int duration;
}
```

This is my template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.21.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.21.2-8434a0bd7c3bbc37cbf916f2968d35e4b165821a  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Simple_Blue" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9c135acb-7dac-47b2-905f-5df4527e1fdb">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mongo-connection"/>
    <queryString language="MongoDbQuery">
        <![CDATA[{
  "collectionName": "assignment",
  "aggregate": [
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "memberId": 1,
        "bookId": 1,
        "borrowingDuration": {
          "$divide": [
            { "$subtract": ["$endDate", "$startDate"] },
            { "$literal": 86400000 }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="bookId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="borrowingDuration" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="memberId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{bookId}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="33">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="32" forecolor="#666666" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="aea6a421-1033-450d-b8fa-98eb17a4de48"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[bookId]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="455" height="32" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="1e8f0089-2e61-4b8c-80a3-90ec8174a6b9"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="24" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{bookId}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="32" width="595" height="1" forecolor="#666666" uuid="e741bd4e-aeef-426c-a2b7-95b0a1f38120"/>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="Group2">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{borrowingDuration}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="32">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="455" height="32" forecolor="#006699" uuid="97fe286b-c429-4b32-b265-88af433b0abd"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="22" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{borrowingDuration}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#666666" uuid="4c3b2255-049c-458f-b3e2-91f319e4e094"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[borrowingDuration]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="Group3">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{memberId}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="32">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="455" height="32" forecolor="#006699" uuid="b6d561e6-9865-4ad9-8621-997525c14aef"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="20" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{memberId}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#666666" uuid="b895387d-9a26-477d-8d2b-21458afc57f5"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[memberId]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="72">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="595" height="92" backcolor="#006699" uuid="527313f3-f700-43bf-b184-56fcef4afbb1"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="20" y="20" width="234" height="43" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="62f0909f-4201-49be-8bac-95d5d30e1185"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="34" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[TITLE]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="395" y="43" width="180" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d5666361-4cd9-48e9-8907-7cd16e9fcf81"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="14" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Add a description here]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="13"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="21">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="20" width="595" height="1" forecolor="#666666" uuid="f2d0af12-fa73-4906-b8f3-fa10d0287892"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="54">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="10" width="555" height="1" uuid="2374ca52-7dd1-4ede-8363-0934a6844a1e"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="17">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="515" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="59261b44-683a-405d-8d05-3372747af075"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="515" y="4" width="40" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="acf9584b-1a7c-4909-9a31-dbbd1646df61"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="100" height="13" uuid="6b28d113-69a6-482b-ac16-617d15fcc1e3"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/report")
    public byte[] generateReport() throws Exception {
        try{
            List<AssignmentDTO> assignmentDTOList= assignmentService.findAll();
            Map<String, Object> params= new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("CompanyName", "Uzan");
            params.put("AssignmentList", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(assignmentDTOList));

            JasperPrint assignReport= JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperCompileManager.compileReport(ResourceUtils
                    .getFile("classpath:duration.jrxml").getAbsolutePath()), params, new JREmptyDataSource());

            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(assignReport), null, HttpStatus.OK).getBody();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).getBody();
        }
    }
```

and I get this error :
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the "MongoDbQuery" language.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57142362/876298